# Burn the [utilities] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [utilities](/questions/tagged/utilities) tag looks like it has attracted lots of the same types of off topic questions as the [tools tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202684/burninate-tools). I suggest we close any [off topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Butilities%5D+closed%3Ano) then burninate it.

Comment: But it's a useful utility for finding off topic questions tagged [utilities]!

Answer (score 2):

As Cole Johnson pointed out, it's helpful to identify off-topic questions. So it's a symptom but not a cause?

But on the other hand, should there be questions tagged "utilities" on meta?

Interesting quandary: do you get rid of a signal that helps you enforce policy, or do you shut down the signal in the hopes that its disappearance will cause fewer violations of policy?

As a matter of pure enforcement, the disciplinarian in me says get rid of it, but as a matter of strategic enforcement, perhaps it should remain.

This is a choose-your-own-adventure answer. I can't decide.